# How to make query to my Firebase database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need make query to my database .

The structure of my database looks like this

```
            "songsDB" : {
"0" : {
  "kzSongAuthorName" : "AuthorName",
  "kzSongComposerName" : "",
  "kzSongGenre" : "NationalMusic",
  "kzSongSinger" : "",
  "kzSongText" : "SongText",
  "kzSongTitle" : "SongName",
  "kzSongytblink" : "",
  "stars" : {
    "ZDA1SrW8XObrLMZ9AZggDJeKyGx1" : true
  }
},
"1" : {
  "kzSongAuthorName" : "Халық әні",
  "kzSongComposerName" : "",
  "kzSongGenre" : "Халық әні",
  "kzSongSinger" : "",
  "kzSongText" : "Есік алды қара су бойламадым-ей,\nБұл жалғанның өтерін ойламадым.\n\nА, құрбым, айдай-ау.\n\nБұл жалғанның өтерін білген болсам-ей,\nҚұлын-тайдай айқасып ойнамадым.\n\nА, құрбым, айдай-ау.",
  "kzSongTitle" : "А, құрбым, айдай-ау",
  "kzSongytblink" : ""
},
"2" : {
  "kzSongAuthorName" : "Халық әні",
  "kzSongComposerName" : "",
  "kzSongGenre" : "Халық әні",
  "kzSongSinger" : "",
  "kzSongText" : "Ақша қарда жорытқан қояндайсың-ей,\nШөп-шөп сүйсем бетіңнен оянбайсың.\n\nА, шіркін, жанай-ау.\n\nЕкі көзің күн нұры жарқыраған-ей,\nҚандай жанға өмірлік баяндайсың.\n\nА, шіркін, жанай-ау.\n\nАры өтейін аулыңнан, бері өтейін-ей,\nАқ алмасын арудың тере өтейін.\n\nА, шіркін, жанай-ау.\n\nШын пейіл, шын көңілің менде болса-ей,\nАлтын қобыз қолға алып әндетейін.\n\nА, шіркін, жанай-ау.",
  "kzSongTitle" : "А, шіркін, жанай-ау",
  "kzSongytblink" : ""
}


"user-posts" : {
"ZDA1SrW8XObrLMZ9AZggDJeKyGx1" : {
  "-Lc0yxGvpLtQsC5rn1O1" : {
    "genre" : "Райм и Артур",
    "kzSongAuthorName" : "Поп",
    "kzSongComposerName" : "https://youtube.com/watch?v=Nb0pN6ONQqc",
    "kzSongSinger" : "Райм и Артур",
    "kzSongText" : "Раим и Артур",
    "kzSongTitle" : "Саукеле",
    "kzSongytblink" : "Текст",
    "starCount" : 0
  },
  "-Lc15vqWWUJthDF_8KVN" : {
    "kzSongAuthorName" : "Genre",
    "kzSongComposerName" : "https://www.youtube.com/watch? V=Nb0pN6ONQqc",
    "kzSongGenre" : "Author",
    "kzSongSinger" : "Singer name",
    "kzSongText" : "Composer",
    "kzSongTitle" : "Song name",
    "kzSongytblink" : "Text",
    "starCount" : 0,
    "uid" : "ZDA1SrW8XObrLMZ9AZggDJeKyGx1"
  },
  "-Lc17GNtP0dRJTOAM7Tw" : {
    "kzSongAuthorName" : "Author name",
    "kzSongComposerName" : "Composer name",
    "kzSongGenre" : "Genre name",
    "kzSongSinger" : "Singer name",
    "kzSongText" : "Text name",
    "kzSongTitle" : "Song name",
    "kzSongytblink" : "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nb0pN6ONQqc",
    "starCount" : 1,
    "stars" : {
      "ZDA1SrW8XObrLMZ9AZggDJeKyGx1" : true
    },
    "uid" : "ZDA1SrW8XObrLMZ9AZggDJeKyGx1"
  }

"users" : {
"ZDA1SrW8XObrLMZ9AZggDJeKyGx1" : {
  "email" : "itteam1602@gmail.com",
  "username" : "itteam1602"
}
```

}

I did this one way, I check the key "star" if the user has UID values true, then you need to show this post in the list

public Query getQuery(DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
        return databaseReference.child("songsDB").orderByChild("stars").orderByValue(getUID()).equalTo(true);
    }

This code dont work(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
return databaseReference.child("songsDB")
    .orderByChild("stars")
    .orderByValue(getUID())
    .equalTo(true);
```

to

```
return databaseReference.child("songsDB")
    .orderByChild("stars/" + getUID())
    .equalTo(true);
```